# Преобразование строки в выражение с переменной

Tags: c#, строки

Как можно преобразовать строку такого вида "5 + x/5 - x^2 * 3" в выражение, что бы пользователь смог задать x? Нашел одну [библиотеку](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) и несколько методов, но там идет преобразование без переменной. Задание x в самой строке до её компиляции мне не подходит

Comment: Нужный вам пример находится в самом низу по ссылке, которую вы привели.

Comment: @andreycha Точно, не заметил, спасибо